# filtering records based on two other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, subquery, ms-access-2010

I need to generate a list of active customers in an MS Access database.  All past and present customers are stored in a customers table.  However, the criteria for determining active status needs to be derived from two other tables: intake and exit.  A customer is considered active if they have an intake date which does not have an exit date after it.  However, to confuse things, a former customer who has an exit date can become a customer again by getting a new intake date.

Here are the relevant parts of the structure of the three tables that store this information:

```
customers table  
    customerID  
    name  

intake table  
    intakeID  
    customerID  
    intakeDate  

exit date  
    exitID  
    customerID  
    exitDate
```

A customer can have multiple intake records and multiple exit records. So the pseudocode for the SQL statement needs to look something like:

```
SELECT customerID, name FROM customers  
WHERE ((most recent intakeDate)>(most recent exitDate(if any)))
```

What should this look like in real SQL?  For an MS Access 2010 database. Obviously, joins are necessary.  But what types of joins?  And how does it need to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ActiveCustomers.*, tblAddress.* FROM 
(
  SELECT customers.name, customers.customerID,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(intakeDate) 
    FROM intake 
    WHERE customers.customerID = intake.customerID AND Len(intakeDate & '') > 0
  ) AS IntakeCount,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(exitDate) 
    FROM exit 
    WHERE customers.customerID = exit.customerID AND Len(exitDate & '') > 0
  ) AS ExitCount
  FROM customers 
) AS ActiveCustomers
INNER JOIN tblAddress ON ActiveCustomers.customerID = tblAddress.customerID
WHERE IntakeCount > ExitCount
AND tblAddress.CurrentAddress = True
```

Comment: Thank you. +1 for a quick thoughtful response.  You suggest counting the intakes and exits rather than explicitly return intake dates more recent than any exit date?  Also, I am going to be creating a report in MS Access that pulls data from three other tables to fill in information for the active customers identified by this query.  Do you have any general comments on how I would set that up? Would I nest even more SQL statements, or would I simply have each field in the report do its own query to find the other information based in the customerID identified for its row by this query?

Comment: You can but you don't have to have sub queries for the other tables.  If using the above, you could JOIN right to `ActiveCustomers`.  For example `FROM ActiveCustomers INNER JOIN OtherTable ON ActiveCustomers.CustomerID = OtherTable.CustomerID`.  Then where I have `SELECT *` you would specify all of the field you want.

Comment: Thank you again. The thing that is confusing is how I should bundle the ActiveCustomers code. Let's say I also want to add a field with the phone number of each active customer's current address, if a current address is specified in one of that customer's address records in the address table, or leave phone number blank if no address is checked as current.  Where do I put the following: "INNER JOIN tblAddress ON ActiveCustomers.customerID = tblAddress.customerID 
WHERE tblAddress.CurrentAddress=-1" ? I hope to be able to put the other segments together myself after seeing your answer

Comment: The line "SELECT customers.name, customers.customerID" is actually "SELECT customers.customerID, customers.firstName, customers.lastName" in my code.  But no matter how I order these three fields, Access can only see the first two, and gives a dialog box asking for the value of the third field in the list. At the moment, it is leaving lastName empty in the resulting datasheet.  Any idea how to get Access to see all three fields?

Comment: I'm not seeing how the above SQL could work. Surely there would be an error at lines 3--4?

Comment: You are right,  it was missing a comma.  i made the correction

Comment: Also, the exit table could have, for a particular customer, two old exit records and one new intake record. There's nothing in this table design that stops this. So we can have an active customer with more exits than intakes. To get around this I think it's best to use the event dates rather than the number of events.

Comment: Btw, if you don't @-mention me in your comments, Stack Overflow won't notify me of your reply 

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
    (SELECT  CustomerID, Name, MAX(intakeDate) AS intakeDate, MAX(exitDate) AS exitDate
    FROM  customerstable 
    INNER JOIN intaketable 
    ON customerID = customerID 
    INNER JOIN  exitdate 
    ON intaketable.customerID = exitdate.customerID
    GROUP BY dbo.customerstable.CustomerID ) c
where intakeDate > exitDate
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I try to run this in access, it gives me a dialog box saying there is a missing operator, and the point in the code where the message starts is ON customerID=customerID INNER JOIN...  Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh sorry, that line should be: ON customerstable.customerID = intaketable.customerID

Comment: Thank you.  I had actually already tried that.  My code is now verbatim like yours, but access is still saying there is some sort of missing operator.  Is a comma or something missing?

Comment: Sorry - the group by line is wrong.  remove the 'dbo.' before  customerstable.CustomerID.  Should look like this:  GROUP BY customerstable.CustomerID.  I'm used to writing SQL for SQL Server and included a schema that isn't valid in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

I like @sqlgrl's approach of just looking at the most recent intake and exit for each customer, but I have adapted it to use MS Access-specific syntax and also, I think, tightened up the join logic a little bit:

```
select c.*
from ([customers table] as c
inner join (
  select customerID, max(exitDate) as lastOut
  from [exit date]
  group by customerID
) as [out]
on c.customerID = [out].customerID)
inner join (
  select customerID, max(intakeDate) as lastIn
  from [intake table]
  group by customerID
) as [in]
on c.customerID = [in].customerID
where [in].lastIn > [out].lastOut
```

The above basically says:

- Build a list of each customer's most recent exit date
- Build a list of each customer's most recent intake date
- Join the two lists with the customers table
- If the customer's most recent intake date is after their most recent exit date, include this customer in the final output